change visual studio color of active intellisense item (Duplicate)
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
change visual studio color of active intellisense item
Maybe this can be solved with an extension, but need in Visual Studio
Part of that question:
"Currently, the difference in VS for the current item in intellisense is - it is bold, which is nice. I wish to change the color of it also, so I will see clearly the current parameter I should enter."
https://i.sstatic.net/Kenr9.png

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi@Meloz，what is the version of VS you are using?  I suggest you use VS2022 since the color of the current item in intellisense is default to blue.

What is the version of Visual Studio you are using?
If you are using Visual Studio 2022, you will find the color of the current item in intellisense is already default change to blue and it is bold.
For example:

If you want to change the color of intellisense parameters, you can go to Tools->Options->Fonts and colors->User Members-Parameters

If you are using an old versions(e.g:2013), i suggest you upgrade to the latest version(VS2022) because the latest version ensures you have access to the newest tools, features, and improvements and they are in support.
Update

The current parameter in IntelliSense is typically highlighted in bold by default but customizing the color is not supported at the present.
I suggest you can submit a feature request from Visual Studio Forum
Expectation:
In the Display items list, "Current Parameter" or similar items related to IntelliSense need to be added.
That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

Nothing changes at all. Clarify, I want change color ONLY current selected parameter. Can you add a screenshot where you were able to change the color of this parameter to red? VS2022

Sorry for ignoring the ONLY current selected parameter. The settings above work for all parameters.
